# Defining custom GNU make functions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What is the problem with the dep2 function in the sample code below?

```
dep1 = $(eval makefile_list_$1 := $(MAKEFILE_LIST))$(eval -include $1.mk)$(eval MAKEFILE_LIST := $(makefile_list_$1))

define dep2
$(eval makefile_list_$1 := $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
$(eval -include $1.mk)
$(eval MAKEFILE_LIST := $(makefile_list_$1))
endef

$(call dep1,test)
$(call dep2,test)

.DEFAULT_TARGET: all
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $@
```

GNU make 3.81 and 3.82 produce `Makefile:10: *** missing separator.  Stop.` which points to the dep2 call, dep1 is run without errors. The only difference between the two variants is the newlines in dep2 (and the whole point why I'd like to use define).

Answer (score 11):

<strike>You forgot the `=`:

define dep2 =</strike>

**EDIT:**
Put a semicolon at the end of each line. I've tested this and it works (in GNUMake 3.81).

```
define dep2
$(eval makefile_list_$1 := $(MAKEFILE_LIST));
$(eval -include $1.mk);
$(eval MAKEFILE_LIST := $(makefile_list_$1));
endef
```

*Why* these semicolons are necessary I don't know, but in the documentation `define` seems to be used for multi-line "variables" only when defining sequences of shell commands to be used in recipes, not Make commands, so maybe the rules are a little different.

Comment: No, the `=` is optional (and was only introduced with GNU make 3.82). Adding it does not make a difference.

Comment: @g.b.: Did you actually try it? I did (with GNU make 3.81), and it did make a difference. It works as expected for me, if I add the `=`.

Comment: @eriktous: Yes, I tried with 3.82. Older versions will just completely ignore the define statement if it is followed by a `=` which is why you don't get the error message.

Comment: @g.b., @eriktous, if that's true then my answer is worthless. I was using 3.81 and going by the documentation (I don't use `define` much); I verified that `=` prevents the error but not that it produces the desired behavior. Let me try some more experiments...

Comment: Semicolons indeed make this work, however I haven't been able to find anything on their usage outside recipes in the GNU make manual so I'm a bit uncomfortable relying on such behavior and will probably go back to single line definitions in this case. The "why" would really be interesting here.

Comment: @g.b.: Ah, I see. I hadn't noticed that. How quaint. @Beta: It even works for me, if I only add a semicolon to the first line, or even if I add an empty line with just a semicolon as the first line inside the define. I can make heads nor tails of it.

Comment: @eriktous: Oh great, now I won't get any sleep tonight, thank you very much.

Comment: The only relevant thing on semicolons I could find in the make manual is in Appendix B on errors generated by make: `if the line has a semicolon as the first non-whitespace character; make interprets this to mean you left out the "target: prerequisite" section of a rule`. Note that the result of the `eval` function is always the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I would move the `$(eval ...)` calls outside of `dep2`. By doing it this way, there's no need for semicolons in `dep2`. This means doubling the `$` signs of some expansions to avoid expansion being done too early. So:

```
define dep2
makefile_list_$1 := $$(MAKEFILE_LIST)
-include $1.mk
MAKEFILE_LIST := $$(makefile_list_$1)
endef

$(eval $(call dep2,test))

# Quick checks for testing, to be removed from the final code...
$(info $(makefile_list_test))
$(info $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

.DEFAULT_TARGET: all
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $@
```

I've tested the code above and it works with Gnu Make 4.0. I would expect it to work back to Gnu Make 3.8x. The `$(eval $(call ...))` pattern is what I always do to execute my custom functions, and I've used it for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the below line to kill the error:

```
FOO := $(call dep2, test)
```

I guess the reason is the early version of gcc (3.8.1/2) can only accept nothing as the return of expression.

eg `$(info string)` returns nothing, but `$(call dep2, test)` returns 2 newlines charaters.

Answer (score -1):

There is much that can be improved in what you are doing.   For one thing you really want to factor the eval calls to a single call at the top.

Your particular problem,  however,  stems from not understanding that the multiline recursive string the make's define command uses never includes the lady new line.   The most natural convention for writing evalable functions is

define Foo 
Line1 
Line2

endef

You can look at the string eval is seeing and see what this does via the info command, e.g.
$(info $(call Foo,x) $(call Foo,y)).